# How to print string in C++ using getline

Tags: c++, string, getline

Why this doesn't print the first word of sentence?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string sentence;
    std::cout<<"Enter sentence: ";
    std::cin>>sentence;
    std::getline(std::cin,sentence);
    std::cout<<sentence;
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter

> "This is text"

output would be

> " is text"

Comment: Remove `std::cin>>sentence;`. You are reading the first word with that.

Comment: Your bug is `std::cin>>sentence;` it reads the first word into sentence then the next line overwrites that first word with the rest of the sentence.

Comment: `std::cin>>sentence` basically reads the first word of `sentence`, and thus now `std::cin` only has `" is text"` left, which is then copied into `sentence` using `getline()` (which overrides `sentence`), and then you print out `sentence`, which is == `" is text"` . So to fix your issue, just remove `std::cin>>sentence;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need the first cin (std::cin>>sentence;), this will solve your problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string sentence;
    std::cout<<"Enter sentence: ";
    std::getline(std::cin,sentence);
    std::cout<<sentence;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cin>>sentence;
```

This line of code takes the first word you input.
Remove it and you are good to go